# App:Uses não funciona no servidor

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Criei uma *class* na pasta Lib do [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) com algumas funções. Testando localmente, e adicionando no *controller*

```
App::uses('readMessages', 'Utility');
```

Tudo funciona corretamente, mas quando faço upload para o server real, diz que não encontra a *class* readMessages.

Alguém sabe como contornar isto? 
Existe algum ficheiro de configuração que preciso de modificar?

Localmente meu servidor é [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) e online meu servidor é [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)

Comment: Existe alguma diferença entre seu servidor local e o publicado? Isso parece ser um erro comum entre servidores [tag:windows] e [tag:linux]

Comment: sim, localmente uso windows, o server é linux...

Comment: Qual o nome do arquivo? Exatamente como ele é escrito?

Comment: Pasta: lib/Cake/Utility/ReadMessages.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[windows](/questions/tagged/windows) e [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) possuem uma diferença básica para a nomenclatura de arquivos, o Windows não é *Case Sensitive* e o Linux sim onde segundo a [wikipedia](/questions/tagged/wikipedia)

> Case sensitive é um termo da língua inglesa que significa sensível ao tamanho, ou sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas, ele é usado para indicar que há diferenças entre letras com caixa alta e com caixa normal. Métodos e comando em um programa ou um compilador, faz a distinção entre os tamanhos da letras.

Sendo assim o [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) considera dois aqrquivos nomeados`teste.php` e `Teste.php` como arquivos de mesmo nome, o que não acontece no [linux](/questions/tagged/linux).

Para a *class* `APP` do [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) o primeiro parâmetro remete ao nome do arquivo que será importado, sendo assim recomendo sempre utilizar o nome do arquivo igual ao que está alocado na sua pasta, o que no caso seria

```
App::uses('ReadMessages', 'Utility');
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.